# PANDAS: Need help counting the instances of a list of items present in a column, and the summing the value in another column that matches

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have a Dataframe like:

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
data = {'PRACTICE': [1,2,3,1,1], 'Postcode': ['BT1234', 'BT4321', 'AB1234', 'BT1234', 'BT1234'], 
        'month': [datetime(2013, 4, 1), datetime(2013, 4, 1), datetime(2013, 4, 1), datetime(2013, 3, 1), datetime(2013, 3, 1)],
        'VTN_NM': ['Gabapentin', 'Gabapentin', 'Diazepam', 'Diazepam', 'Gabapentin elixir'], 
        'Total Items': [6, 5, 11, 4, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

and a list of search terms for the VTM_NM column:

```py
search_terms = [
    'Gabapentin', 'Pregabalin', 'Tramadol', 'Oxycodone',
    'Morphine', 'Diazepam', 'Temazepam', 'Codeine',
    'Buprenorphine', 'Methadone', 'Methylphenidate'
]
```

I want to count/sum the Total Items column for all the search terms when list items are present in the VTM_NM column, based on the month, PRACTICE and postcode columns. So when any of the items in the list are present in the VTM_NM column it adds the Total Quantity for that given month practice and postcode value. The counted values could then be stored in a new column e.g. gabapentin_count etc. If gabapentin was prescribed 5 times in one month by a practice of a given postcode then the total count for each of the 5 prescriptions would be added.

So for this input, the output should look like:

| PRACTICE | Postcode | Month | Gaba_count | Diaz_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BT1234 | 2013.3 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | BT1234 | 2013.4 | 6 | 0 |
| 2 | BT4321 | 2013.4 | 5 | 0 |
| 3 | AB1234 | 2013.4 | 0 | 11 |
| etc |  |  |  |  |

I think I need to use `groupby()` to solve this problem, but I can't figure it out, and none of the code I found online works either. How can I get this result?

Comment: It would be best if you removed the image and replaced it with 1.) **BEST** Some code that can recreate your dataframe e.g. pd.DataFrame({"SomeColumn":["some","data"}) or 2.) **GOOD** a table formatted in markdown as a representation of some of your data. Then, add an `Expected Output` section so that we know exactly what it is that you want to get (as a table preferably)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and note my [edit]s to the question - the most important thing to keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**. Posts are about **the question** and **the code**, not about you or your level of experience (either in programming or with using the site).

Answer (score 3):

Filter your data using your list like so:

```
df2 = df[df['VTN_NM'].isin(search_terms)]
```

Then pivot your data:

```
df2 = df2.pivot_table(index=['PRACTICE', 'Postcode', 'month'], 
                      columns=['VTN_NM'], 
                      fill_value=0, 
                      aggfunc='sum')
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
                             Total Items
VTN_NM                          Diazepam Gabapentin
PRACTICE Postcode month
1        BT1234   2013-03-01           4          0
                  2013-04-01           0          6
2        BT4321   2013-04-01           0          5
3        AB1234   2013-04-01          11          0
```

---

Or maybe you mean to search for each term and fix the column:

```
df['VTN_NM'] = df['VTN_NM'].str.extract('(' + '|'.join(search_terms) + ')')
```

Pivoting, same as above:

```
out = df.pivot_table(index=['PRACTICE', 'Postcode', 'month'], 
                     columns=['VTN_NM'], 
                     fill_value=0, 
                     aggfunc='sum')
print(out)
```

Output:

```
                             Total Items
VTN_NM                          Diazepam Gabapentin
PRACTICE Postcode month
1        BT1234   2013-03-01           4          3
                  2013-04-01           0          6
2        BT4321   2013-04-01           0          5
3        AB1234   2013-04-01          11          0
```

---

Or, a combination of the two... where you fix and then filter. It's not fully clear from your post.

---

Using groupby, you weren't off thinking about that route:

```
df['terms'] = df['VTN_NM'].str.extract('(' + '|'.join(search_terms) + ')')
print(df.groupby(['PRACTICE', 'Postcode', 'month', 'terms'])['Total Items'].sum().unstack('terms').fillna(0))

# Output:

terms                         Diazepam  Gabapentin
PRACTICE Postcode month
1        BT1234   2013-03-01       4.0         3.0
                  2013-04-01       0.0         6.0
2        BT4321   2013-04-01       0.0         5.0
3        AB1234   2013-04-01      11.0         0.0
```

Comment: I work in transplant research and one thing that OP should clarify is if "Gabapentin" and "Gabapentin Elixir" are to be classified as the same thing. Is OP's list of search terms just descriptors or are they medicine codes? Should "Gabapentin" be grouped with "Gabapentin Elixir"? I see that your edits are addressing this and agree that it is an important distinction.